# Unpacking variadic tuples in c++17

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, structured-bindings, fold-expression

Is there anything better in c++17 (maybe C++2a) than the classic C++14 way to unpack variadic tuple with [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)?

Anything better than this:

```
template <typename ...I>
class MultiIterator
{
public:
    MultiIterator(I const& ...i)
        : i(i...)
    {}

    MultiIterator& operator ++()
    {
        increment(std::index_sequence_for<I...>{});
        return *this;
    }


private:
    template <std::size_t ...C>
    void increment(std::index_sequence<C...>)
    {
        std::ignore = std::make_tuple(++std::get<C>(i)...);
    }

    std::tuple<I...> i;
};
```

Like [fold expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fold-expression), [structured-bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/structured-bindings?mixed=1)? Any hint? I can accept answer why I cannot use these mentioned C++17 features here - but I prefer "solution.

Comment: BTW, what's the purpose of the *std::ignore* assignment ? is it to document the intent ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes more or less yes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since C++14 we have generic lambdas, and since C++17 we have fold expressions and `std::apply` effectively hiding the usual unpack logic:

```
std::apply( [](auto&... i){ ((void)++i,...); }, some_tuple );
```

---

note: *for your information, the (void) thing is just to avoid any custom comma operator to kick in... you never know :)*

Comment: nice, but still a hack. Upvoted because it it's not your fault the C++ doesn't allow a straight syntax.

Comment: @bolov yep, the most hackish thing is the need to use the comma operator; I wonder why we cannot just `expr;...;` ... but I guess this would be problematical grammar-wise

Comment: Can apply you solution to my example with increment? I mean some example of usage

Comment: @PiotrNycz yes, just replace the `increment()` call with the above, with `some_tuple` replaced with the `i` member